# 404 Error when Loading Website from Visual Studio with Default.aspx File Open

Tags: asp.net

I am having an issue running a developing ASP.NET website from Visual Studio 2019.

Whenever I have the Properties tab for the project open and click the Run button, it loads the website with the "Default.aspx" file just fine. However, when I try to run the website with the Default.aspx file open in VS, the website returns a 404 error from IIS. I noticed that when I ran the website with the file open in VS, "/Default" was added to the end of the URL, but when the file wasn't open in VS, nothing was added to the end of the URL.

I do not know if I need to adjust a setting, or if my project was misconfigured from the start.